# PoolExhaustedException in Dropwizard server

Tags: mysql, connection, dropwizard, pool, reconnect

I am using dropwizard with Mysql database server. The maximum connection value for this server is set to 32, for every fetch the the number of active connection increases and once it reaches 32 I get a PoolExhaustedException.

Note that I am only opening and closing the session when needed and creating a connection only once. Also following are some of the DB configurations in my yaml

```
database:
 # the name of your JDBC driver
 driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  # the username
 user: root

 # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deploys?autoReconnect=true?

   # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
   properties:
   charSet: UTF-8
   hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
   hibernate.show_sql: true

   # the maximum amount of time to wait on an empty pool before throwing an    exception
  maxWaitForConnection: 1s

  # the SQL query to run when validating a connection's liveness
  validationQuery: "/* MyApplication Health Check */ SELECT 1"

  # the minimum number of connections to keep open
  minSize: 8

  # the maximum number of connections to keep open
  maxSize: 32

  # whether or not idle connections should be validated
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: false

  #Whether or not connections will be validated before being borrowed from   the pool. If the connection fails to validate, it will be dropped from the pool, and another will be borrowed.
  checkConnectionOnBorrow: true
```

Not sure whats going o, but should the autorecoonect be false?  Or is there a confiuration to kill abandones connections from the connection pool?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the `maxWaitForConnection` value.